# What is the difference between DesiredCapabilities vs RequiredCapabilities?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, remotewebdriver

Can somebody tell me the difference between the `DesiredCapabilities` vs `RequiredCapabilities` in RemoteWebDriver constructor?

Here is the link for the constructor:
http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/remote/RemoteWebDriver.html#RemoteWebDriver(java.net.URL,%20org.openqa.selenium.Capabilities,%20org.openqa.selenium.Capabilities)

Comment: Whoever down voted the question, if you don't know the answer..why don't you just sit quiet :)

Comment: I'm having the same question here..

Comment: Even i'm looking for this for quite some time.. Can any one please respond???

Answer (score 1):

Currently you needn't worry about the `requiredCapabilities`, because it's been deprecated in Selenium v3.4.0.

Answer (score 0):

For the benefit of those who find this question and still haven't found the answer, please look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35313035/) by [Andrew Regan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/954442/andrew-regan) to the same question asked again slightly differently by [Dev Raj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2596035/dev-raj).

I haven't seen any one use it or any blog posts - so far - (I haven't gone out in search of one, but the usual ones I read) never mentioned this constructor with requiredCapabilities. So, it seems to be a less popular feature that is available!