# Where do we use this Constructor RemoteWebDriver(java.net.URL remoteAddress, Capabilities desiredCapabilities, Capabilities requiredCapabilities)

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

I was going through Webdriver API and come across a constructor in [RemoteWebdriver](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/remote/RemoteWebDriver.html) for which i didn't find any information.

I have used the below constructor to [configure selenium grid](http://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/how-to-configure-selenium-grid)

```
    RemoteWebDriver(java.net.URL remoteAddress, Capabilities desiredCapabilities)
```

Here is an other constructor which is there exactly below that, **'Capabilities requiredCapabilities'**

```
 RemoteWebDriver(java.net.URL remoteAddress, 
 Capabilities desiredCapabilities, Capabilities requiredCapabilities)
```

Can any one please let me know where this can be applied.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [changelog](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/commit/2cd1f37f2dcfc86fccc604de1ddef599f1c7ca63) for 2.25.0:

> Added support for "requiredCapabilities" to the remote webdrivers and implemented basic support for these in the firefox driver. Failure to fulfull a required capability will cause a `SessionNotCreatedException` to be thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Currently you needn't worry about the `requiredCapabilities`, because it's been deprecated in Selenium v3.4.0. Use `desiredCapabilities` instead.